# Запятая перед первым "ИЛИ". И др

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Тео́рия за́говора — приписывание скрытых причин некоторому **событию,
> или** ряду событий, или всей наблюдаемой картине действительности,
> и**ли, на**оборот, **сокрытия** таких причин от широкой публики некоторой
> группой влиятельных лиц или организаций. Многие сторонники теории
> заговора утверждают, что крупные исторические события управлялись
> заговорщиками, которые манипулировали ходом событий, сами оставаясь
> «за кулисами».

ВОТ ССЫЛКА: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/978389

Почему здесь перед первым "ИЛИ" запятая стоИт? Ошибка?

Смущает слово "сокрытиЯ". По-моему, здесь это слово должно в единственном числе стоять (сокрытиЕ).

Перед "наоборот" запятая не нужна?

Comment: Ребята, не ругайтесь там!Я вообще вас не знаю. Никого не знаю. О ваших тёрках и подводных течениях - не в курсе. Я просто увидел сообщение Sharon и не понял, почему там запятой нет. А потом там slava1947 поставил много точек, я чего-то написал. Я понятия не имею, кто такой Слава, кто такая Шарон. Наверняка хорошие и достойные люди. Сообщение с вопросом о многоточиях адресовано конкретной особе, с которой мы 5 лет не разговариваем. Чтобы наладить отношения, я даже врал, что раком болею.Но... но она до сих пор обижена! Сорри, если кого обидел. Не хотел!Задал нов. вопрос только чтобы объясниться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Снимите галочку, чтобы я мог удалить ответ. Не хочу больше возиться с этим предложение ни секунды больше. Будь проклят человек, который соорудил это предложение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133697/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett------).

Answer (score 2):

Правильная запись: *Тео́рия за́говора — **приписывание** скрытых причин некоторому событию, или ряду событий, или всей наблюдаемой картине действительности **или, наоборот, сокрытиЕ** таких причин от широкой публики некоторой группой влиятельных лиц или организаций.*

Упрощенная запись:

Тео́рия за́говора — **приписывание** скрытых причин событию, или ряду событий, или всей  картине **или, наоборот, сокрытиЕ** таких причин от широкой публики группой лиц или организаций.

Здесь три группы однородных членов с союзом ИЛИ.

(1) Приписывание скрытых причин (чему?) событию, или ряду событий, или всей  картине. Союз ИЛИ — повторяющийся (со второго члена), запятые ставятся.

(2)  Приписывание скрытых причин или, наоборот, сокрытиЕ таких причин. Союз ИЛИ одиночный, запятой нет.

(3) сокрытия таких причин  группой влиятельных лиц или организаций. Союз ИЛИ одиночный, запятой нет.

Итак, найденные ошибки: одна лишняя запятая после слова **картине**; окончание Е в слове ***сокрытиЕ.***

Comment: Сокрытие — это уже не теория заговора, это действительно заговор. Поэтому: "Тео́рия за́говора — приписывание скрытых причин событию, или ряду событий, или всей картине или, наоборот, [приписывание] сокрытиЯ таких причин от широкой публики группой лиц или организаций". Если что здесь неверно, то слово "наоборот", потому что противопоставления нет.

Comment: По мне так все нормально.  Теория заговора - это  предположение о существовании такого заговора. А потом описывается сам заговор, причем вполне ясно.  А лишние слова-канцеляриты не нужны. Кака разница: сокрытие причин или приписывание сокрытия причин.  Все отглагольные существительные согласно информативному стилю должны безжалостно уничтожаться, а вы их тут "разводите", ага?

Comment: Теория заговора — это одно, сам заговор — это иное. // Разница большая: приписывать можно то, чего нет. Скрывать причины можно, только если они есть, а приписывать сокрытие причин можно, даже если их нет. // Без канцелярита это звучит так: Тео́рия за́говора — это когда приписывают скрытые причины некоторому событию, или ряду событий, или всей наблюдаемой картине, а также когда приписывают группе влиятельных лиц, что она скрывает от общественности истинные причины неких событий.

Comment: Ладно, вы меня не слышите, останемся каждый при своем мнении. Только вот интересно , вы поняли, что теория заговора — это условный термин.  Люди во все времена  (начиная с античности) думали, что существует группа, которая тайно всем управляет, манипулируя фактами.  Что касается отглагольных монстров, то сформулируйте свою мысль без них, чтобы люди быстро, на слух понимали вас. В противном случае ваши высказывания  вызывают сомнение.

Comment: Иногда без девербативов не обойтись. // Теория заговора — это термин, объясняющий конкретное явление. Термин, впрочем, может быть многозначным, но тогда словарную статью следует делить на пункты.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что союз «или» присоединяет пояснительную конструкцию (обычно обозначающую одно и то же понятие другими словами).

Пример: *Бабушка показала мне деревянный ларь, или ящик, широкий вверху и узкий внизу.*

Comment: Нет, там повторяющиеся союзы.  Пояснения — они выражают то же самое понятие другими словами. Ларь = ящик. А в вопросе вы никак не можете приравнять "некоторое событие" к "ряду событий" и "всей наблюдаемой картине".

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Запятая стоит перед каждым *"или"* потому, что в предложении однородные члены, соединённые повторяющимся союзом.

Пример из Розенталя:

> Там белые рубахи баб, да пёстрые рубахи мужиков, да голоса, да
> звяканье проворных кос.

Для запятой после "...действительности" не вижу оснований.

**2** "Сокрытия" относится к слову "приписывание".

> Тео́рия за́говора — приписывание скрытых причин некоторому событию...
> или [приписывание] сокрытия таких причин...

Comment: @Nektoid в вашем же правиле у Розенталя идёт следующий пример: "Всякий вечно позабывал в кухне или шапку, или кнут для чужих собак, или что-нибудь подобное". Перед первым "или" запятой нет. Розенталь. § 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами.

Comment: @Theej потому что перед первым "или" в вашем примере нет однородного члена. Сравните: "Всякий вечно позабывал в кухне шапку, или кнут для чужих собак, или что-нибудь подобное" — вот это будет аналогично предложению в вопросе.

Comment: @Nektoid по-моему, вы путаете соединительные союзы с присоединительными союзами "и", "да", "да и", перед которыми запятая ставится.

Comment: @Theej не путаю.